# Python converting a list to set, big O

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

and thanks for help

```
words = [....#Big list of words]
words_set = set(words)
```

I have hard time determine what is the complexity of set(words) when n=len(words).
Is it O(n) since it moves on all the items of the list, or O(l(n-l)) when l is a single word length?
Thanks for help! If there is a difference between WC and BC too.

Edit: don't mind O(l(n-l)) it's mistake for repeating substring big O.

Comment: I don't think "word length" is of significant importance, or rather assuming all words are the same length it should be a constant influence and thus insignificant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand your second option, but iterating a list is O(n) and you must iterate the list to convert it to a set. Any operation on each element - eg hashing - is a constant factor which is dominated by the linear time of iteration.

Comment: You are right, I confused it with another algorithm complexity. So it's O(n). Thanks very much

Comment: @nadirc: note: an *individual* `a_set.add(word)` might be `O(n)` but it is amortized `O(1)` unless [`words` list is constructed specifically to cause quadratic behavior](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703#msg150522).